# reboot solaris to "ok" prompt

Tags: solaris, sparc

I need to reboot a solaris sparc machine to the "ok" prompt so I can do a net jumpstart reinstallation on a machine. I have remote access to the machine via the ALOM. How can do do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have system console, you can issue an "init 0" to shut the machine down without rebooting.  This should drop you to an "ok".  You may need to send a stop-a if the "ok" doesn't appear.  Sometimes the system hangs going down.

Answer (score 1):

On a Sun keyboard, press the two keys <kbd>STOP</kbd> and <kbd>A</kbd>.  That will get you an OK prompt.

The `init 0` will poweroff the Unix/Linux computer.
(yes I know this post is very old)

Comment: boot -s will boot to single user mode.

Comment: Access Method  --> What to Do  
  (1) Graceful shutdown of the Solaris OS  -->    
From a shell or command tool window, issue an appropriate command (for example, the shutdown or init command) as described in Solaris system administration documentation.
  (2) L1-A (Stop-A) keys or Break key -->    
From a Sun keyboard connected directly to the Sun Fire V445 server, press the Stop and A keys simultaneously. -or-  From an alphanumeric terminal configured to access the system console, press the Break key.

Comment: (3)ALOM system controller console or break command
From the sc> prompt, type the break command. The console command also works, provided the OS software is not running and the server is already under OpenBoot firmware control.
  (4) Externally initiated reset (XIR)  -->
  From the sc> prompt, type the reset -x command.
  (5) Manual system reset --?  From the sc> prompt, type the reset command.